# Count filename characters, then copy those files to another directory

Tags: bash, copy, character, filenames, filesize

I need to write a bash script that copies the files to **dir2** that match the character count in their filename with a given int value given as an argument to the script. I've tried to do something but I cannot manage to get the files copied at all.

```
read number

list=`for file in *; do echo  -n "$file" | wc -m; done`

for file in $list

do

if [ $file -eq $number ]

then

cp file dir2

fi

done
```

Comment: Do the filenames contain extensions and do they count towards the character count?

Comment: No, the extensions do not need to go towards the char count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `list` is a list of filename lengths, not filenames. So $file is just a number.   You also missed the leading `$` on `$file`.

You don't need t use the `wc` program, you can get the length of a variable name using `${#name}`.  I think you need something like this:

```
while [[ $number != +([0-9]) ]]
do
    read -p "Enter number: " number
done

for file in *
do

    if (( ${#file} == $number ))
    then
        cp "$file" dir2
    fi

done
```

Comment: Your's is a much better answer I think than mine; my only recommendation would be to use double brackets and maybe do `read -r`. +1

Comment: If I was using double brackets I would use `(( ${#file} == $number ))`, `[[ ]]` are for pattern matching.  The `-r` is only necessary if the user is entering \ characters, which would not be appropriate since an integer is required - either with or without the `-r` the input would be wrong.  Some validation of `$number` would be good. to add

Comment: Yeah, too bad you can't do `${#file%*.*}`, that would also take care of matching only the filename without extension.